# Como separar registros de una consulta a traves de ResultSet

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente problema , trato que, a partir de una consulta que se guarda en un `ResultSet` ingresar la información de la consulta(regresa una tabla) en un archivo `txt`, el problema que se me presenta es que guarda tal cual toda la consulta, no respeta ni espacios, ni si son diferentes registro o no.

Mi código es el siguiente

```
 ResultSet rs;
 rs =statement.executeQuery("select *from empleado;");
 while(rs.next()){
   for(i=1;i<11;i++){
      linea=rs.getString(i);
      pw.print(linea+"|");
      System.out.print(linea);
   }
 }
```

Ya trate de buscar alguna función con la variable `ResultSet` o manipularlo con ciclos pero no encuentro la manera de separar registros.

Comment: ¿ En que falla su código ? no se entiende muy bien que desea lograr .

Answer (score 0):

Cuando escribes en el fichero de texto, estás escribiendo una línea seguida de otra, al igual que la imprimes por consola, una solución fácil y sencilla es agregar un tabulador por cada dato escrito y por cada registro escrito, agregar un nuevo salto de línea.

EL código te queda:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // Escribir campos de registro.
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
        linea = rs.getString(i);
        ps.print(linea + "\t");
        System.out.print(linea+ "\t");
    }
    // Fin de registro.
    ps.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```

Como puedes observar, **ps** se corresponde con:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream("C:\\Users\\Fernando Pacheco\\Desktop\\temp.txt");
```